# MS-Access : How to sum multiple values from different tables according to dates

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two similar tables as follows

---

### Table 1

```
Date           Amount     Tax
4/1/2016       1000       100
4/1/2016       2000       200
5/3/2016       1500       150
5/6/2016       1000       100
5/6/2016       3000       300
7/9/2016       2500       250
```

---

### Table 2

```
Date           Amount     Tax
4/1/2016       1000       100
4/2/2016       3000       300
5/3/2016       1500       150
5/9/2016       4000       400
8/11/2016      3000       300
10/9/2016      2000       200
```

dates can be similar or different in both tables.
I want two queries. 
First, a query which gives me sum of amount and tax from each date from both tables between required dates. Eg: Table 1 have 2 entries and table 2 have 1 entry for 4/1/2016. so the result should be as below (summing up all three entries)

```
Date           Amount     Tax
4/1/2016       4000       400
4/2/2016       3000       300
5/3/2016       3000       300
5/6/2016       4000       400
5/9/2016       4000       400
7/9/2016       2500       250
8/11/2016      3000       300
10/9/2016      2000       200
```

Second,a query which gives of sum of amount and tax for each month from both tables between required dates. Eg output as below

```
Date           Amount     Tax
4/2016         4000       400
5/2016        11000      1100
7/2016         2500       250
8/2016         3000       300
10/2016        2000       200
```

Query that have I have written till now( not working )

```
SELECT date, sum(Amount),sum(Tax)
From Table1
WHERE Date BETWEEN #04/01/2016# AND #12/31/2016#
UNION ALL
SELECT date, sum(Amount),sum(Tax)
From Table2
WHERE Date BETWEEN #04/01/2016# AND #12/31/2016#
GROUP BY Date
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For first query, consider a union query derived table with outer query aggregation:

```
SELECT q1.[Date], SUM(q1.Amount) AS DayTotalAmt, SUM(q1.Tax) AS DayTotalTax
FROM
  (SELECT [Date], Amount, Tax
   FROM Table1
   UNION ALL
   SELECT [Date], Amount, Tax
   FROM Table2
  ) AS q1
GROUP BY q1.[Date]
```

For second query, consider using first query as a source with another outer query layer that runs a `WHERE` filter with month/year aggregation:

```
SELECT Format(q2.Date, "M/YYYY"), SUM(q2.DayTotalAmt) AS MonthTotalAmt, 
       SUM(q2.DayTotalTax) AS MonthTotalTax
FROM
  (SELECT q1.[Date], SUM(q1.Amount) AS DayTotalAmt, SUM(q1.Tax) AS DayTotalTax
   FROM
     (SELECT [Date], Amount, Tax
      FROM Table1
      UNION ALL
      SELECT [Date], Amount, Tax
      FROM Table2) AS q1
   GROUP BY q1.[Date]
  ) AS q2    
WHERE q2.Date BETWEEN CDate("4/1/2016") AND CDate("12/31/2016")
GROUP BY Format(q2.Date, "M/YYYY")
```

Or if you save first query:

```
SELECT Format(q.Date, "M/YYYY"), SUM(q.DayTotalAmt) AS MonthTotalAmt, 
       SUM(q.DayTotalTax) AS MonthTotalTax
FROM Query1 q
WHERE q.Date BETWEEN CDate("4/1/2016") AND CDate("12/31/2016")
GROUP BY Format(q.Date, "M/YYYY")
```